# Is linking number invariant under automorphisms of $S^3$?

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be two oriented links in $S^3$ an let $\phi : S^3 \to S^3$ be a diffeomorphism.  Is $lk(K_1,K_2) = lk(\phi(K_1), \phi(K_2))$?

Comment: This should follow almost immediately from any definition of linking number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. And you can prove it using homology.